# RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)と出力されます。

Tags: python, python3, pytorch

> https://github.com/pytry3g/pytorch-example/tree/master/nlp/rnn/wikipedia

上記githubのtest_model.pyとtrain.pyを実行すると、共に、
以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yudai/デスクトップ/wikipedia/test_model.py", line 53, in <module>
model = RNN(n_vocab, embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
File "/home/yudai/デスクトップ/wikipedia/test_model.py", line 22, in init
self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, n_vocab)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 46, in init
self.reset_parameters()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 49, in reset_parameters
stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(self.weight.size(1))
RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

本当に困っています。
何卒、よろしくお願い致します。

## 環境

OS は Ubuntu です。

```
$ uname -a
Linux NAGARE 4.15.0-30-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 26 17:42:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ライブラリ:pytorch

```
torch                             0.4.1    
torchvision                       0.2.1

$ python3 -V
Python3.6.6+
```

Comment: 自分でも動かしてみたところ、 `python get_dataset.py` でデータが生成されていないようでした（nobunaga.txtなど作成されるものの、中身が空でした）。yepさんの環境ではどうなりましたか？

Comment: [get_dataset.py](https://github.com/pytry3g/pytorch-example/blob/master/nlp/rnn/wikipedia/get_dataset.py#L32) の `re.findall("<p>.*</p>", html)` の部分ですが、複数行に対応する必要がありますので、`re.findall("<p>.+?</p>", html, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)` と変更する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: 遅れてすみません。私の環境も全く同じです。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。get_dataset.pyでtxtファイルにデータが取れるようになりました！

Comment: しかしながら、先ほどとは、少し違ったRuntimeErrorが発生してしまいます。

Comment: get_dataset.py、data_util.py、train.pyを実行した結果です。RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/146993